# Rails 3 - CarrierWave and CloudFiles extremely slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, cloudfiles

I have an Rails 3 application where I upload files (photos) using CarrierWave to Rackspace CloudFiles. This works perfectly. But when displaying a list of 10 to 20 photos back on a page it takes a very long time >15 seconds. It seems to take time to resolve or put each URL back together.

Is this similar issue to this but for :cloud_files provider:
https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/issues/261

Is there a good work around for this? I don't need to verify that each files is valid.

**UPDATE:**
Just wanted to share this info. I switched over to CarrierWave with Fog - Fog configured to use Cloud Files and the issue was not present. Problem solved. Any one else experience this too?